# Phone charger basic question

Tags: charger, wire, copper

I'm (kinda) new to electronics and I have a simple question... So, I have a phone charger and I cut the wire because I wanted to connect the PWR and the GRD to another circuit. But when I connected the multimeter to the wires I get no readings. I believe this has to do with the wire (it has multiple copper wires...)

[image: This kind of wire]

I'm used to work with simple wires on arduino (not the copper ones) and this may be a dumb question but i'm really lost here :(

Comment: Are you sure your measuring the right two wires?

Comment: Attach pictures, schematics or specifics (such as model number, voltage rating, etc) about the charger to allow people to help you better.

Comment: I can almost guarantee you it has nothing to do with the fact that the wires are stranded.

Comment: is your multitester sets to DC reading....its also posible that youve may not notice that it set on AC reading so the result is no reading in DC

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the charger is a switch mode power supply (SMPS) and needs a load to operate. When you measure across the supply with a multimeter the instrument's impedance is to large to make the supply start. Try connecting a resistor to draw a few milliamps and measure the voltage across it.